# How to validate JSON from API via serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm new in Django and I know how to use model serializers, but I can't find information about how to validate data from API. For example,
I have a method that gets a data from another web service.

```
def get_sales(self):
    url = "https://statistics-api.com/api/v1/sales"  # I can't add real url, sorry
    body = {"dateFrom": f"{datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)}"}
    try:
        request = requests.get(url, params=body)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            return True, request.json()
        return False, request.json()["errors"]
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        return False, f"Response is not in JSON format"
```

The response example. Smth like this:

```
(True, [{'date': '2023-03-03T13:02:22', 'barcode': '46134548641', 'totalPrice': 500, 'discountPercent': 52}]
```

So, I need to get the data from response in my views.py:

```
sales = api.get_sales()
  result, sales_info = sales
  if result:
     try:
        prices_count = []
        for element in sales_info:
          price = element.get("totalPrice", "")
          prices_count.append(price)
        transactions_total = sum(prices_count)
```

I know this is not the best practice, because of KeyError. How can I validate data via serializer?

Comment: Hi, the url doesn't seem to be working can you update it? Also, if possible, the best way to ask is by generating a minimum reproduceable example.

Comment: the response json format is not a json please check out here:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.piheyi

Comment: Hi! I can't add real url because it needs credentials, anyway you can't check it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. API response is in JSON format, but my function returns a tuple (Boolean, List[dict]).